# Heroku Rails - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When I post something in my Rails app (locally), it works perfectly. However, when I deploy it on Herokuapp, it breaks. Here is what I have:

```
#Gemfile

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', group: :development
gem 'pg', '0.18.1', group: :production
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

#database.yml

production:
<<: *default
adapter: postgresql
database: db/production.sqlite3
```

I then proceeded to deploy my app to Heroku like this:

```
git add .
git commit -m "comment"
git push heroku master
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku run rake db:seed
```

I've checked my version using the following:

```
heroku run rake db:version
>> Current version: 20171103035018
rake db:version
>> Current version: 20171103035018
```

Finally, here is my controller where I perform a *create* action:

```
#suggestions_controller.rb

def create
    @suggestion = Suggestion.new(suggestion_params)

    if @suggestion.save
        flash[:notice] = "Suggestion successfully posted!"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        flash[:error] = "Suggestion failed to post!"
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end

private
    def suggestion_params
        params.require(:suggestion).permit(:suggester, :ip, :suggestion_type, :title, :body)
    end
```

I tried this on my *localhost* and it creates just fine, but when I deploy it on Heroku, it displays this error:

[image: heroku error]

I'm pretty certain I did everything correctly and I have no idea what's breaking here.

Thanks for any help.

**Edit:** I just got a lead to the problem. It says that my *created_at* is `null`.

`ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint`

I'm researching on the web now to see how I can fix this problem.

Comment: `heroku --logs` should give you an idea. Also, remember to run `heroku run rails db:migrate` or create to set up your DB, Heroku doesn't do that automatically.

Comment: the `heroku logs` really helped me solve this problem. thanks CD-RUM

Answer (score 3):

Well, you should take a look at your logs. Heroku documented their logging here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging
From your description, it may be something about your database setup, e.g. wrong database.yml.
If the logs don't help you, please fix the indentation of your database.yml posted above.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. It was indeed this particular error message:

`ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint`

I had to add this line of code to my `suggestions_controller.rb`

```
def create
    Suggestion.record_timestamps = true; #added this line of code
    ... #other logic
end
```

When I upvote and downvote a post, I don't want it to update the *timestamps* such as this:

```
def upvote
    Suggestion.record_timestamps = false;
    ... #other logic
end
```

I redeployed my app and it works fine now.